# Is there a closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{q^{-n^2}}{n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-sum

I found that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{-n^2}$ can be expressed using a [theta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function). Is there also a closed form for the following series?
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{q^{-n^2}}{n}$$

Comment: Theta functions aren't exactly "closed form".

Comment: We have had this question before, but I don't know how to search for it.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\sum_{n\geq1}q^{-n^{2}}\cos\left(2nz\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\theta_{3}\left(z,\frac{1}{q}\right)-1\right)$$
 then if we integrate with respect to $z$
  we get $$\sum_{n\geq1}q^{-n^{2}}\frac{\sin\left(2nz\right)}{2n}=\frac{1}{2}\int\theta_{3}\left(z,\frac{1}{q}\right)dz-\frac{z}{2}.$$ Now you can make an estimation, because a I think there isn't a closed form of your series.

Comment: So are you assuming that $$\sin{\left ( \frac{\pi}{2} n\right )} = 1$$ or am I missing something?