# Closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k+1}{q^{k(k+n)}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

What are, if they exist, closed forms for the series
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{q^{k(k+n)}}, \qquad\qquad \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{q^{k(k+n)}}, \qquad\qquad \text{ for }q>1,\;n\in \mathbb{N}?$$

The annoying factor is the $k^2$ in the exponent. I tried to solve them with some elementary manipulations or massive amount of google searching, but I didn't find anything. Only it seems to be close to [this series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203558/is-there-a-closed-form-for-sum-n-1-infty-fracq-n2n).

**Motivation** I ask because I am trying to analitically continue to zero the zeta function
$$\zeta(s) := \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty \sum_{k\geq 1} (2k+n) e^{-tk(k+n)} t^{s-1} dt,$$
and to use the Mellin direct mapping theorem I need the asymptotic of the sum for $t\rightarrow 0$. Using $q = e^{-t}$ our sums arise.

Thanks!

Comment: These would diverge.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Wait, $1/q^k \to \infty$...

Comment: Sorry, my fault, $q>1$!! I edit the question!

Comment: I would complete the square and try to use the result in the question you linked to.

Comment: @nayrb Thanks, actually I tried to complete the squares, isolating then the $k^2$-factor, but the question I linked doesn't seem to provide any closed form for the series I'm interested into. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Write $k(k+n) = (k+n/2)^2+(n/2)^2$, take out the $(n/2)^2$ term to get $1/4(2k+n)^2$ which for $n=2m$ even gives $(k+m)^2$. So you can write your sum as a finite series and the function in the other question. For odd $n$ there might be something you can do. I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to express the first one this in terms of  $\Theta$-functions + some finite series?